# Как сделать подобный input?

Tags: jquery, css

https://www.tinkoff.ru/loans/cash-loan/ Не реклама!

Внизу форма, в этой форме есть поле для ввода телефона. 
В нем:

1. есть неудаляемая часть текста "+7("
2. placeholder появляется при вводе текста
3. маска

2 пукнт совсем не понимаю как реализовать, а 1 и 3 вроде сделал, но тоже. Они конфликтуют...

```
    $(function(){
  $("#phonereg").mask("+7 (999)999-99-99");
});

var $inp = $("#phonereg"), prevVal = '',
    reference = "+7(";

function change (val) {
    var ind = val.indexOf(reference);

    if (ind !== 0) {
        $inp.prop("value", prevVal || reference);
    } else {
        prevVal = val;
    }
}

$inp.on("input", function () {
    var val = $(this).prop("value");
    change(val);
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/gob6u82m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Наподобие такого?

```js
var mask = "+7 (999)999-99-99",
    mask2 = "+7 (___)___-__-__";
var $inp = $("#phonereg"), 
  $inp2 = $("#phoneregback"), 
  prevVal = '',
    reference = "+7 (";
    
$(function(){
  $("#phonereg").mask(mask);
});
$inp.on("input", function () {
  $inp2.prop("value", mask2);
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if(val.indexOf(reference) == -1) {
   $inp.blur();
  $inp.prop("value", reference);
    setTimeout(function() {
     $inp.focus();
    }, 100);
  }
});
$inp.on("focus", function () {
 $inp2.prop("value", mask);
});
$inp.on("blur", function () {
 $inp2.prop("value", " ");
});
$('#phonereg').on('keydown', function() {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  if(val == reference) {
    if( (key == 8) || (key < 48 || key > 57))
      return false;
  } else {
   if((key > 46 && (key < 48 || key > 57)))
      return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#phoneregback {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #dcdcdc;
}
#phonereg {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="phoneregback" value="" placeholder="">
<input type="text" id="phonereg" value="+7 (" placeholder="">
```

Comment: Да, только, чтобы нельзя было удалить +7

Comment: в хроме тестил, не удаляется

Comment: хм. Только что удалилось, потом еще раз запустил и всё ок) 
Спасибо за подсказ)

Comment: Если начать вводить, потом выделить всё и удалить - удаляется

Comment: Ну и такой вариант по сути костыль, а я думаю можно реализовать как-то иначе.
На сайте примере - реализовано не так. Пытался найти как - не удалось. )

Comment: в целом я поправил код, сейчас работает вполне хорошо) Может есть решение из коробки в jquery, но не в курсах)

Comment: Запретили выделение? 
Ну это как-то... Не честно по отношению к пользователю)

Comment: Нет, не блокировал, там можно выделять

Comment: ctrl+a не пашет

Comment: точно, я плохо потестил, значит надо дописывать вариант для этой комбинации

Comment: плагин Masked Input для jQuery решит вашу проблему.